# Options for fastapi with graphql and mongo

Tags: mongodb, graphql, fastapi

I would like to start a new project making use of fastapi. i would prefer mongodb as the storage backend and I would also like to have the whole thing 'speak' graphql.

In early 2022; what are the options? I see there's [graphene-mongo](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-mongo)... but I can't seem to find anything else.

Comment: Are you looking for entirely self-hosted or to make use of cloud services?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to develop something with this tech stack but without success so far.

I am a front-end developer and am diving into the full stack universe. After trying many languages, frameworks and databases, this technology stack I found the most interesting for what I intend to do because of its flexibility.

But for now, I could not advance much and also found the same difficulty as you, very few examples available on the web.

My small example application uses FastAPI, is already connected to the MongoDB Atlas database and I tried using the Graphene library to expose a graphql endpoint of the database query result, but so far I haven't achieved any meaningful result.

I have also tried using the Strawberry library, which is suggested by the FastAPI documentation, but haven't achieved much yet either.

I will keep pushing to make this tech stack work and if I succeed, I can share my experience with you if you are still interested.